# Error installing Spree_Shared gem:

Tags: ruby, rubygems, spree

I am trying to get the [spree_shared](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_shared) gem to work. I install a clean spree installation on postgres and then add spree_shared to the Gemfile, then run bundle install.
After this running rake db:migrate gives me this error:

rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Spree::Base
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spree_core-2.3.3/app/models/spree/preference.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in`require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/spree_shared-f649514b71d8/lib/spree_shared/spree_preferences_extensions.rb:12:in`'

(Full error output is here: http://pastebin.com/WJ70bhti)

Anyone succeeded in getting this to work?

Additional notes: I have followed the instructions in the readme about adding the config files for Apartment etc. and it doesn't change this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your using a newer version of spree then the extension supports. Spree::Base was only recently added. I would open an issue on the extensions github.